# Entity Framework NullReferenceException in Where

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following line of code that calls into my Entity Framework and is returning a Null Reference Exception.

```
List<FieldGroup> fieldGroups = dataContext.FieldGroups.Where(fieldGroup => fieldGroup.Field_Catalog_Id == fieldVersion.FieldCatalogId && fieldGroup.Field_Catalog_Version == fieldVersion.FieldCatalogVersion).ToList();
```

`fieldVersion` is being generated earlier in the method and I have confirmed that it, and its fields `FieldCatalogId` and `FieldCatalogVersion` are not null and have proper values.

My context, `dataContext`, while poorly named is connecting to my database and it does have rows in the FieldGroups table. I have also confirmed that a row with `Field_Catalog_Id` and `Field_Catalog_Version` matching the values being requested in the where exist so it should be able to find rows to return.

I can't determine why the line is throwing a NullReferenceException. Any ideas are appreciated. Let me know if I can provide any more useful info.

**Edit:** I did take a look at the locals when the exception was being thrown and nothing that was being referenced was showing up null.

I added in Debug.Assert to check that `dataContext`, `dataContext.FieldGroups`, `fieldVersion`, `fieldVersion.FieldCatalogId`, and `fieldVersion.FieldCatalogVersion` are not null before the problem line. The code got past all 5 of those asserts and still threw a NullReferenceException. I can't find anything within those fields that is null that could be causing the exception.

Comment: What does it return without where?

Comment: Is your properties mapped correctly to their table columns?  Is your table mapped correct to the table name?  Is your `dataContext` null?

Comment: `fieldVersion` is most likely null.

Comment: Queries don't throw random NullReferenceException. Add `Debug.Assert(dataContext != null); Debug.Assert(dataContext.FieldGroups != null); Debug.Assert(fieldVersion != null); Debug.Assert(fieldVersion != null); ` before the query and see which one explodes

Comment: You should be able to tell what's null when the exception is thrown. Hover over everything and try to see what's not looking right, look at locals...

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)